# onbeforeunload in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, event-handling, dom-events

In my application I need to call logout function in `onbeforeunload()` so I did the code as below:

```
window.onbeforunload = function(){
bodyWidth = window.document.body.offsetWidth;
bodyHeight = window.document.body.offsetHeight
mouseX = window.event.clientX;
mouseY = window.event.clientY;
    if((mouseX<0) || (mouseY<0) || (mouseX > bodyWidth)  || (mouseY > bodyHeight)){
        logout();
    }
}
```

It work fine when I close the window by pressing the <kbd>(X)</kbd> button in IE.

But if I closed the IE window by press the <kbd>ATL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> this not worked. Before executing the `logout()` function the browser gets closed.

Can any one help me with the proper using of `window.onbeforunload`.

I even tried with the below functionality, but it did not work:

```
logout=true;
window.onbeforeunload = bfunload;
window.onunload = unloadPage;
function bfunload(){
    bodyWidth = window.document.body.offsetWidth;
    bodyHeight = window.document.body.offsetHeight
    mouseX = window.event.clientX;
    mouseY = window.event.clientY;
        if((mouseX<0) || (mouseY<0) || (mouseX > bodyWidth)  || (mouseY > bodyHeight)){
            logout=false;
            logout();
        }
    }
    function bfunload(){
    if(logout){
        logout();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future do not bold every single line of your question. It does nothing to help you getting an answer.

Comment: Is this a high-security site you are working on? Please don't use JavaScript as a user-system engine. It is easily disabled on any browser making it very flawed for user logging.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to know all of the actions that close a window. The code will never run if the user kicks the cord on their desktop. A hurricane comes and knocks out the power. If they loose an internet connection. If they navigate away via the address bar/bookmark.

Only way to handle ending sessions is session timeout on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript `window.onbeforeunload()` event is fired just before the web page is unloaded. 
This gives us the ability to make sure that the user is certain about leaving the page that they are viewing.

By pressing `Alt+F4` the OS closes the Browser application directly. If no windows are open it will bring up the shut down dialog.

The preferred way to perform `Logout Functionality` is to use `Sessions` in your application.